# Get resources with dynamic parameter filtering using ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement the dynamic filtering capabilities for the Web APIs similar to OData $filter (only eq operator though) using ASP.NET Web API 2. But I am not using the OData feature.

example -

```
GET /order?id=134017710&orderdate=20-01-2014&status=new
```

I don't want to restrict static parameter bindings while retrieving the resources.

The way I thought of implementing it using the Dynamic LINQ to filter out the results.

Any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public class QueryObject
{
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public OrderController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] QueryObject query) 
    {
         // some method (possibly uses Linq)that acts on your filters
         FilteredGet(query.id, query.orderDate, query.status);

    }
}
```

This should allow you to allow parameters to be null and you can adjust your LINQ query as your query changes.

Comment: This is good approach. This way probably i can keep the filter list restricted instead of for all the attributes of the entity.